# std::accumulate BinaryOperator side effects

Tags: c++, c++11

[std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) documentation on cppreference.com states that:

> op must not invalidate any iterators, including the end iterators, or
>   modify any elements of the range involved (since c++11)

Later, it is shown a possibile implementation, that I report here:

```
template<class InputIt, class T, class BinaryOperation>
T accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init, 
             BinaryOperation op)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        init = op(init, *first);
    }
    return init;
}
```

How op could "invalidate some iterators" or "modify elements of the range", assuming this implementation of std::accumulate ?

Comment: `[&vec](int a, int b) { vec.clear(); return a + b; }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a lambda that modifies the elements in the range and/or modifies the range itself. For example, using the following lambda would be a violation of `std::accumulate`'s preconditions:

```
std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,3,4};
auto illegal_op = [&v](int init, int val) { 
    v.back() *= 2;      // modifying elements in the range
    v.push_back(42);    // invalidating iterators in the range
    return init + val;
};
std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, illegal_op);
```